# Tablesorter server side pagination - requirements for different Ajax options

Tags: jquery, pagination, server-side, tablesorter

I intend to use tablesorter's Ajax server side pagination functionality but have a couple of questions about how it works. The documentation for 2.10.0 says:

> The ajaxProcessing function was updated to only require a total number of rows to be returned, also instead of returning an array of table rows, you can build the table yourself and just return the jQuery object containing those rows

If you build the table yourself (which I assume means the full HTML for the next set of rows, including cell values), does the ajaxUrl still need to return JSON information for the set of rows or should it return the HTML for the table? If the JSON information is to be returned, how is the table input into the jQuery?

The ajaxProcessing can return just the total rows and $rows as an object or array, or also the headers: what determines which is the best choice of these options? How is the $rows object created? In general how should the code be changed to effect these different options?

Sorry if I'm a little slow on this and thanks for any pointers.

Regards,

lindon

---

Continuing my question here with more detail on one thing I'm confused about:

My ajaxUrl will get the next set of rows as HTML and the normal syntax for pagination (i.e., without table sorter) is:

```
databasequery.php?offset=0&numrows=25
```

Offset and numrows are variables that are defined as part of the php call. It's not clear to me how to use this together with `size={size}&page={page}` in order for this to work properly with table sorter.

Appreciate any tips. Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original [`ajaxProcessing` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing) required that you returned:

- total rows (required),
- rows; within an array of arrays
- optional header cell text

in this strict format:

```
// [ total_rows (number), rows (array of arrays), headers (array; optional) ]
return [
  100,  // total rows
  [
    [ "row1cell1", "row1cell2", ... "row1cellN" ],
    [ "row2cell1", "row2cell2", ... "row2cellN" ],
    ...
    [ "rowNcell1", "rowNcell2", ... "rowNcellN" ]
  ],
  [ "header1", "header2", ... "headerN" ] // optional
]
```

Now, the rows can be returned as a jQuery object of the rows, which the addon then adds and updates (this is just an example):

```
var i, j, rows = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
  rows += '<tr>';
  for (j = 0; j < data.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
    rows += '<td>' + data.rows[i].cells[j] + '</td>';
  }
  rows += '</tr>';
}
// [ total rows, $rows (jQuery object; optional), headers (optional) ]
return [ data.total, $(rows), data.headers ];
```

Lastly, you can add the rows yourself and just return the total rows:

```
var i, j, rows = '';
for (i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
  rows += '<tr>';
  for (j = 0; j < data.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
    rows += '<td>' + data.rows[i].cells[j] + '</td>';
  }
  rows += '</tr>';
}
$('#mytable').find('tbody').html( rows );
// [ total rows, headers (optional) ]
return [ data.total ];
```

Similar examples of the above are also included in the documentation of the [`ajaxProcessing` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxprocessing)

So, to answer your questions

> does the ajaxUrl still need to return JSON information for the set of rows or should it return the HTML for the table? If the JSON information is to be returned, how is the table input into the jQuery?

the [`ajaxUrl` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#pager-ajaxurl) doesn't need to return anything. It is merely used as a method to get the next set of data by sending the appropriate page number, filter queries and column sort directions to the server. It shouldn't be returning any HTML. The pager addon will update the table after it has been processed.

> How is the $rows object created? In general how should the code be changed to effect these different options?

Hopefully the example I shared above answers that question. But as stated, the above code is just an example as the ajax returned can be in pretty much any format. It is just no longer required that you have to build the array of arrays to return to the pager addon.

> what determines which is the best choice of these options?

The best choice is left to you. The pager addon was written to give you more choices as to how you want to apply the ajax data. You could actually completely bypass the pager plugin and do the ajax processing yourself, then just update the pager. That's what makes the system flexible and hopefully work in many different situations.

---

In answer to your continuation try using this as your `ajaxUrl` string:

```
databasequery.php?offset={page}&numrows={size}
```

If `numrows` is fixed at 25 rows, then you can remove the `{size}`, as I would guess your server side script would always return at most 25 rows worth of data:

```
databasequery.php?offset={page}
```

Comment: Thanks Mottie. The next set of data that the ajaxUrl option is used to get: does it need to be in JSON format or can it be in HTML? With the server side program I already have in place, it's quite easy for the next set of data to already be in HTML - would it make sense to use that data and if so how would I do that? Apologies if I'm being a little slow on this. Thanks, lindon.

Comment: Yes, you can return HTML in your ajax, it doesn't need to be in JSON format at all. To work with HTML, you'll need to modify the [`ajaxObject` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#pager-ajaxobject) and change the `dataType` to `"html"`.

Comment: Ok great - let me try that.

Comment: The way the queries work in my server-side program, `offset` needs to be the nth record that is the starting record for that page. So on the first page `offset` is 0, on the second page it is 25, etc. So really it is equal to {page} x {size}. Is there a string that will give that  value? Thanks again.

Comment: Then try the [`customAjaxUrl` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#pager-customajaxurl) and ignore using the `{page}` variable.

Comment: If this answer was added to or linked from the documentation of the ajax pager it would massively improve it!